# web scraping with python selenium loop and save problem

Tags: python, selenium, loops, web-scraping

'Hi,I want to save the data I took as csv and txt, but I couldn't.

Moreover;

How can I repeat this process multiple times?'

```
nextInput = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="pnnext"]/span[2]').click()
result = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".GyAeWb cite.iUh30")
```

'
Code;
'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import time
import csv
import re


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url ="http://google.com"
driver.get(url)

searchInput = driver.find_element("xpath",'/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
time.sleep(1)
searchInput.send_keys("dişçi")
time.sleep(2)
searchInput.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
result = driver.page_source
result = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".GyAeWb cite.iUh30")

for index,element in enumerate (result):
  print(index+1,element.text)

result = []
result = list(set(result))
 
time.sleep(2)

nextInput = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="pnnext"]/span[2]').click()
result = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".GyAeWb cite.iUh30")

for index,element in enumerate (result):
  print(index+1,element.text)

count = 1
with open("siteler.txt","w",encoding="UTF-8") as file:
  for item in result:
    file.write(f"{count}-{item}\n")
    count+=1

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    while 1:
        nextInput = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="pnnext"]/span[2]').click()
        result = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".GyAeWb cite.iUh30")

        for index,element in enumerate (result):
            print(index+1,element.text)

        count = 1
        with open("siteler.txt","w",encoding="UTF-8") as file:
            for item in result:
                file.write(f"{count}-{item}\n")
                count+=1
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    print("there is no element with '//*[@id='pnnext']/span[2]' XPATH")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Helped me. I also want to repeat this process 100 times. Or any number?

Comment: with try except implemented in this way, program repeats until nextInput is visible, if you want to limit the number of iterations just use a counter variable and set a limit (i.e 100 if you want)

Comment: Thank you. I will try. The data I take is not saved in txt. Do you have any information about it?

Comment: the code you wrote above doesn't work ? it's seem correct, what you have to do exactly ?.

Comment: I want to save the incoming data in txt, but while the data is coming into txt  

" 1-<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="46be8d133b6d81042982220a3f80c979", element="a178177c-f5bd-4636-8be2-f41d0a95d85a")>"   
it comes this way,  this is wrong.

Comment: because find_elements() function return list of selenium object. So you have to extract data from each element in the list, like:
item.text, item.find_element(By.*, ), ecc...